# Wordpress / WooCommerce Custom Product type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a Custom Product type for Woo commerce, only problem is getting it to work.

i've added a filter for the Product type and it appears in the Dropdown box, however when i click it , it has no boxes other than the SKU .

Is there a certain location that the file has to go that im missing? As i have currently just lobbed it with the other product type files.

Thanks for any help you may give

Comment: Check: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types

Comment: I've looked at that, I was just wondering where i should PUT the class file, As so far nothing i try works.

Comment: The class file, as per the answer, goes in the "includes" directory. It's literally the first sentence of the answer

Comment: Which is where the file is already located, yet still not working. despite being a clean Copy paste of a file (With logical edits such as class renaming and changing the $this->product_type = 'your_type';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add the product class, you also have to manipulate the meta-boxes for the General tab on the product setup pages. The Price box is there, it is just initially hidden unless the product type is "simple" or "external"

There are a few ways to do this. One (not recommended) is to edit the html-variation-admin.php file directly and add "show_if_*customproduct*" to the price group div.

```
<div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external">
```

becomes this:

```
<div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external show_if_customproduct">
```

Another (better) is to add some javascript by calling the *woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data* action:

> add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data','showType');
>
> ```
> function showType(){
>   echo "<script>jQuery('.show_if_simple').addClass('show_if_customproduct');</script>";
> }
> ```

That will turn all "simple" product boxes on for "customproduct" boxes in the general section.

Or, your action can just echo a new div with new boxes, set the div class to "show_if_customproduct," and copy the initial content from the group price div in the html_variations file.

You'll also likely have to add templates for the pages, at the very least to get an "add to cart" buttom. Look under templates/single-product to get the idea.

Comment: Oh, btw, it doesn't really matter where you put the class file, as long as you include it after WC_Product is declared. I don't generally recommend modifying plugin files or folders, updates can really mess you up. I put my class file in my own plugin directory, and include it in a 'plugins_loaded' action.

Comment: This is correct answer... worked for me. Love the jQuery hack.

Comment: I had to hook that jQuery into woocommerce_product_data_panels, to ensure all the inventory fields were displayed correctly too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to create a class for your custom product type. Let say it is `CustomProduct`

```
class WC_Product_CustomProduct extends WC_Product{
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'CustomProduct';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
}
```

and you will put this class under `includes/` folder. After that, you need to activate this product type;

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_custom_product_type' );
function add_custom_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'CustomProduct' ] = __( 'Custom Product' );
    return $types;
}
```

Add this to `functions.php`

Comment: Don't think BionicBear is really good at following instructions. I made a custom product and implemented within 5 minutes

Comment: @BionicBear have you applied all the steps?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I tried your code but it throws an error saying WC_Product is not found do you know why is this happening?

Comment: @Fresher Whic version of PHP & WP do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. . I am using Version 3.9.1 of wordpress and 5.3 of php

Comment: Have you installed WooCommerce?

Comment: Yes WooCommerce is in active only not sure why that errors shows up

Comment: For any body else stumbling across this you need to Require the class file AFTER  woocommerce is loaded wc_product...: 
  add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', array( $this, 'includes' ) );
worked for me .

Comment: And don't forget to include or require WC_Product_CustomProduct file .php